# Installation issue with iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0.1 and xcode 4.5.2

Tags: xcode4.5, iphone-5, ota

We have been facing a special scenario for the last week and can not find any solution for it. Here is our configuration info:
Development tool
Xcode 4.5.2, iOS 6.0.1, deployment target 5.0, universal app (iphone+iPad application)
My partner has an iphone 5 with iOS 6.0.1
I have an iphone 4s with iOS 6.0.1

We are using OTA installation process and everything is working fine with iPhone 4s.  However, we are getting an installation error with iPhone 5.

Every time the installation reaches a complete bar, and then the iphone 5 device shows a pop up alert showing "could not install application" error.

We have tried to sort out problem, but still have not had any luck.

We appreciate in advance if anyone can help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through many iterations and different changes, we could not possibly solve the issue. However we created new project and copied/pasted each file and then built application.

**What happened next!!! fortunately application installed on all devices without any issue**. However I wish if we know the exact reasons why it was not installing previously.

Answer (score 0):

Oh and theres a large possibility that this wont work for iphone 5. you might have to connect it and restore it via iTunes. or if you choose not to do that then youre iphone 5 is doomed until somebody comes up with a solution :P

Answer (score -1):

Is it connected to wifi? 
Try that. That should help. Or put a sim, without a sim lock passcode, that has network online. or vice-versa. let me know! :D